# Add method to string and modify self in Lua

Tags: string, lua, io, luajit

How can I add a method to the `string` table and modify self inside it ?

Basically, I'm trying to mimic the behaviour of the `io.StringIO.read` method in python, which reads `n` char in the string and returns them, modifying the string by "consuming" it.

I tried this:

```lua
function string.read(str, n)
  to_return = str:sub(1, n)
  str = str:sub(n + 1)
  return to_return
end

local foo = "heyfoobarhello"
print(string.read(foo, 3))
print(foo)
```

Output is:

```
hey
heyfoobarhello
```

I expected the second line to be only `foobarhello`.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Strings in Lua are immutable. You may wrap a string as an object that keeps track of where to start. Or you can change the API to return the string and the substring.

Comment: @lhf I see, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mimic Python's `io.StringIO` class, you must make an object that stores both the underlying string and the current position within that string. Reading from an IO stream normally does not modify the underlying data.

```
local StringIO_mt = {
  read = function(self, n)
    n = n or #self.buffer - self.position + 1
    local result = self.buffer:sub(self.position, self.position + n - 1)
    self.position = self.position + n
    return result
  end,
}
StringIO_mt.__index = StringIO_mt

local function StringIO(buffer)
  local o = {buffer = buffer, position = 1}
  setmetatable(o, StringIO_mt)
  return o
end

local foo = StringIO"heyfoobarhello"
print(foo:read(3))
print(foo:read())
```

Output:

```
hey
foobarhello
```

I don't recommend adding this class or method to Lua's `string` library, because the object has to be more complex than just a string.

Comment: Why do you write 5.4-only code?  The question has `LuaJIT` tag, it means Lua 5.1.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yes I figured it out myself, I juste removed the tags `<something>`. No worries ;)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: I completely missed that tag. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can add methods to the datatype string independently from the string table.
Short example that shows that the string methods even work if string table gets deleted...

```
string=nil

return _VERSION:upper():sub(1,3)
-- Returning: LUA
```

So you can add a method...

```
-- read.lua
local read = function(self, n1, n2)
return  self:sub(n1, n2)
end

getmetatable(_VERSION).__index.read=read

return read
```

...for all strings.
( Not only _VERSION )

And use it...

```
do require('read') print(_VERSION:read(1,3):upper()) end
-- Print out: LUA
```